# How can I change the window title of python Mayavi?

Tags: python, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

How Can I change the window title "Mayavi Scene 1" to my own?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np

fig = mlab.figure(figure=None, bgcolor=(0,0,0), fgcolor=None, engine=None, size=(400, 400))
data = np.random.rand(3, 3)
x, y, z = np.transpose(data)
mlab.points3d(x, y, z, -y, colormap="RdYlBu", scale_factor=1, scale_mode='none')
mlab.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that:

```
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.figure('My title')
s = mlab.mesh(x, y, z)
mlab.show()
```

([mlab.figure](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_figure.html#figure))